# Hibernate: How specify custom sequence generator class name using annotations?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I want to specify following hbm configuration using annotations:

```
<id name="somePK" column="&quot;somePK&quot;" type="long">
            <generator class="com.db.hibernate.KeyGenerator"/>
        </id>
```

I am not sure how to provide class name with

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_STORE")
```

Do I have to specify `@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator` in each entity class? 
Can I specify just the class name under `@GeneratedValue` annotation?

Comment: The best way to implement custom id generator using Annotation and XML
Visit this link <https://stackoverflow.com/a/50564556/9495226>

Answer (score 21, accepted):

please find below set of code which i have used in project for the same.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "XyzIdGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "XyzIdGenerator",
        strategy = "com.mycompany.myapp.id.BigIntegerSequenceGenerator",
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "xyz_id_sequence")
        })
public BigInteger getId()
{
   return id;
}


package com.mycompany.myapp.id;

import org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator;
...

public class BigIntegerSequenceGenerator
    extends SequenceGenerator
{
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: in hibernate version 5.2.2 SequenceGenerator is deprecated, could you update this example please?

Answer (score 15):

please refer the [custom-id-generator-in-hibernate](http://supportmycode.com/2014/08/22/custom-id-generator-in-hibernate/) this may help you.
In this example, I am creating the sequence number by taking MAX number from primary key table called **pk_table**.

**Employee** Class looks as follows.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "sequence_emp_id", strategy = "com.supportmycode.model.EmployeeIdGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_emp_id")  
@Column(name="employee_id")
private String employeeId;

@Column(name="firstname")
private String firstname;

@Column(name="lastname")
private String lastname;

@Column(name="birth_date")
private Date birthDate;

@Column(name="cell_phone")
private String cellphone;

//Getter and Setter methods.
}
```

**EmployeeIdGenerator** class looks as follows

```
public class EmployeeIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
        throws HibernateException {

    String prefix = "EMP";
    Connection connection = session.connection();
    try {

        PreparedStatement ps = connection
                .prepareStatement("SELECT MAX(value) as value from hibernate_tutorial.pk_table");

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("value");
            String code = prefix + new Integer(id).toString();
            System.out.println("Generated Stock Code: " + code);
            return code;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {       
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Here, we have Implemented the interface `IdentifierGenerator` to override the function `generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)`. the statement `SELECT MAX(value) as value from hibernate_tutorial.pk_table` will get the MAX number from the table pk_table. And then we prefix the **MAX** number with the string "**EMP**".

Output looks as follows:

**EMPLOYEE**

```
------------------------------------------------------------
employee_id | birth_date | cell_phone | firstname | lastname
------------------------------------------------------------
EMP1        | 2014-08-22 | 111        | Nina      |  Mayers
```

Comment: The link is dead unfortunately.