# How to use a custom SequenceGenerator for Hibernate in Spring for all entities?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've implemented a custom `SequenceGenerator` that I want to use in all my entities for the "id". But rather than having to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11632114/398441) for *each* entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "XyzIdGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "XyzIdGenerator",
        strategy = "com.mycompany.myapp.id.BigIntegerSequenceGenerator",
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "xyz_id_sequence")
        })
public BigInteger getId()
{
   return id;
}
```

is there a way to apply this `SequenceGenerator` to ALL entities by default using vanilla Hibernate/JPA or perhaps by using Spring?

Comment: The best way to implement custom id generator using Annotation OR using XML Visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/50564556/9495226

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the code segment to a super class, add add @MappedSuperclass to it. But, in that case, all your entity will use the same seq generator

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class SeqIdable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "XyzIdGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(
    name = "XyzIdGenerator",
    strategy = "com.mycompany.myapp.id.BigIntegerSequenceGenerator",
    parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "xyz_id_sequence")
    })
    public BigInteger getId() {
       return id;
    }

}
```