# How to change the name and value of default ID field of an entity in jhipster

Tags: mysql, jhipster

During Entity creation in jhipster, ID field gets created automatically, with auto-increment feature.

As per my requirement, i want the ID field name as TK_ID, instead of ID. And also, value of the ID field starts with 1 and gets incremented automatically. In my case , i want the value to be started with TK001, and should be auto incremented.

During Entity creation , i want these changes to happen. Is there any way to do this is jhipster application ?

**Requirement: Instead of field name- ID, want as TK_ID..... And Value of ID field should start with TK001, instead of 1.**

Note: I am using mysql for DB and Gateway application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're entering the world of Hibernate/JPA generators. If you look at the [Jhipster entity generator](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/4150df13414dbd86db279729cf2eabf325dd3738/generators/entity/templates/server/src/main/java/package/domain/_Entity.java#L72) you'll see that the ID is a `@GeneratedValue` that uses the `Identity` generation type, not the `Increment` type that you say.

There are many different types of ID generators that are explained over on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10043812/905571).

I would avoid changing the ID attribute itself (the one that is automatically generated by JHipster) to a different name or generation type as it could have a few unintended consequences, and there could be other JHipster dependencies. Simply too messy to edit and manage.

A better way is to create another attribute with the name `TK_ID` and create your own `@GenericGenerator` that takes the ID attribute and adds the prefix you want. e.g. if a new record will have the ID field value of `3`, take it and add the prefix `TK00`.

Have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25438921/905571) for a code example.

Alternatively, you could transform any of your queries to `TK_ID` and point it to `ID` instead, and transform the result back to the format you want. That way you're not adding an extra attribute and changing the way the entity is created.