# Sequence generator : JAVA/JPA/SPRING

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**Question**: Is it possible to generate sequence number not using select someSequence from dual; ?

**Problem** : `@GeneratedValue` and `@SequenceGenerator` by default is using `select someSequence from dual;` to get nextval for my id. But my user doesn't have such rights to select from the dual table so I can use only id = sequence.nextval, but I don't know how to use this in Entity class. Or how should I pass id value to Entity constructor like sequence.nextval?

**Usage:** Oracle DB, CrudRepository, save() method.

Comment: can you make your question clearer please .. if you mean you want to construct a new opject you should just not send id and it will automatically generate it.

Comment: as stated in the question I am using @SequenceGenerator to generate my id, this calls select mySequence from dual; (background process). But I want to get my id using sequence.nextval not using select.

Comment: define the database used, and the JPA provider. JPA provides many different strategies to use, and SEQUENCE is but one.

Answer (score 5):

You need to first create the sequence in Oracle:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE USER_SEQUENCE START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 10;
```

Then annotate your class to look like this:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="USER_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR", sequenceName="USER_SEQUENCE", initialValue=1, allocationSize=10)
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="USER_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR")
    private Long userId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to write yout own strategy and use the `GenericGenerator` annotation. This answer might be helpful for you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25438921)

Comment: does he say he is using Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert id with the help of below query:

```
select max(id) from <<tableName>>;
```

If you cannot select from dual table , then you can query your own table, find the max id, **increment it by 1** and assign it as the new id.

Comment: Yes this can be an option, but I want to use sequence.nextval, because in the future I won't make incremented id.